# Proving $\tau $ is a topology.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be a set and $\sigma: \mathcal{P}(X) \to \mathcal{P}(X)$ a map such that:
>
> 1. $\sigma (\emptyset)=\emptyset $.
> 2. $A \subset \sigma (A)$.
> 3. $\sigma (\sigma (A)) = \sigma (A)$.
> 4. $\sigma (A \cup B) = \sigma (A) \cup \sigma (B)$.
>
> Proof that $\tau = \{ X- \sigma (A):A \in \mathcal{P}(X) \}$ is a topology on $X$ such that $\sigma (A) = \overline{A}$.

I have proved everything except: Given $A_i \in \mathcal{P}(X), \forall i \in J$, then
$\cup_{i \in J} X- \sigma (A_i) \in \tau $

Comment: See also "Kuratowski closure axioms"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X-\sigma(A_i), i \in I$ be open sets from $\tau$ and we need that their union is in $\tau$ too. My claim is that

$$\bigcup_{i \in I} (X-\sigma(A_i)) = X - \sigma(\bigcap_{i \in I} \sigma(A_i)) \in \tau$$

Taking complements on both sides and using de Morgan we see that the first identity  is equivalent to

$$\bigcap_{i \in I} \sigma(A_i) = \sigma(\bigcap_{i \in I} \sigma(A_i))$$

which can be shown thusly:

For any fixed $j \in I$ we have $\bigcap_{i \in I} \sigma(A_i) \subseteq \sigma(A_j)$ so taking $\sigma$ on both sides preserves this inclusion (this follows from axiom 4 of $\sigma$, see below) so that $\sigma(\bigcap_{i \in I} \sigma(A_i)) \subseteq \sigma(\sigma(A_j))=\sigma(A_j)$ and as $j \in I$ is arbitrary we have $\sigma(\bigcap_{i \in I} \sigma(A_i)) \subseteq \bigcap_{i \in I} \sigma(A_i)$. The other inclusion is trivial from 2.

> The lemma from 4: $A \subseteq B \to \sigma(A) \subseteq \sigma(B)$ because 
>   $A \subseteq B$ implies $A \cup B=B$ so $\sigma(A \cup B)=\sigma(A) \cup \sigma(B)=\sigma(B)$ which implies in turn $\sigma(A) \subseteq \sigma(B)$.